# Do I need the "X power" books

Tags: dnd-4e

We've just been using the Character Builder for all the builds and Powers an what have you. Is there enough guidance/play advice in the various Power Books (Divine, Martial, Arcane etc) to make them worthwhile? Why do you think that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the books don't have a ton of fluff. *Primal Power* and *Psionic Power* are the exceptions; they added a fair bit of background material, but possibly not enough to be worth the purchase price on their own.

Answer (score 1):

I have all of the Power books, and I have never actually opened them outside of looking up some text that was not included in the power cards after we've printed them from the character builder.

I find my money is better spent on the campaign setting, DMGs, and Monster Manuals.

Answer (score 1):

The Power Books are largely rules, which can be found on Character Builder.  There is some flavor text, background about the default game setting, but that's probably not worth the price of the book by itself.  Doubly so if you're playing in a different setting (Forgotten Realms, Eberron,etc).

I prefer books to the builder myself so I have a few for use of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy using the books. I usually have a character planned out before I use the character builder and having the books handy helps with that.

Answer (score 0):

Having a subscription to Character Builder I have never had to use a power book at all. I've not bought a single one. I don't feel like I've missed out on anything and am getting on with playing perfectly fine.

I'm happy to never buy one, even if I am missing out I'm never gonna find out that way, and so don't really care.

***[grins]***

Comment: -1: I don't find "Don't know, don't care" to be a useful answer.